# Paypal Rest API Guest Issue

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

To give you an overview of my platform, I am using Angular.js 1.5 and Laravel 5.1. 
I am using the [Paypal REST API SDK for PHP](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK). I have followed the instuctions from this Medium [article](https://medium.com/@Ral15/paypal-sdk-with-laravel-5-1-9d77e3dc55ae). On my front end Angular side, once I successfully call the first "postPayment" function, I receive the redirect url, which I redirect to. Once the user completes their payment successfully on the paypal side, the return url comes back to my confirmation page where I handle the "getPaymentStatus" function from the Medium article.

I am using a Sandbox account for testing purposes right now, but I am able to successfully complete the transaction when a user logs in on the Paypal side. However, when a user tries to go through as a guest "Debit/Credit card", enters their information, and completes the transaction, I receive this 400 error in the console:

POST sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest 400 (Bad Request)
jquery.min.js:5

On my Paypal profile settings, I have activated the Account Optional in the My Selling Tools->Website Preferences.  I have been looking for other instances of this, but I cannot find a solution. I have tried using the test credit cards with various phone numbers, but that does not resolve this issue.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? I am in the dark and do not know how to handle this.

I would appreciate any help in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the best way is to create a ticket with MTS. They would be able to assit you but to get the best support, provide them with your test website, and also the details of your testing. Contact them here. https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics thank you.